# Cannot access SwipeRefreshLayout in eclipse

Tags: android, sdk, android-support-library

I have updated my Android SDK's support library to 19.1 and updated ADT plugin also.

Later I restarted my eclipse I was not able to import `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

I am sure that My SDK has `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Please help me out form this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It won't be available for the existing project. SwipeRefreshLayout will be available for all new projects.

To use it in existing project create new project and copy android-support-v4.jar from new project and replace this jar from your old project jar. After replacing android-support-v4.jar you can use SwipeRefreshLayout in your existing project as well.

Comment: Yes I actually forgot it.. thanks a lot